# Moving specific number of files into newly created numbered folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I currently have around 550 files in a folder with the same format (.csv) and same headers (all started with the letters "YL").

I wonder if there is a way to splits these files (50 files at a time) (order doesn't matter) into numbered folders? (ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) And also create a subsequent folder for the leftover files?

I have found this scripts and tried to modify it for 50 files, but it looks like it only created a the first folder (subdir1)

```
@echo off
set /a counter=1
set /a filesperfolder=50
cd dir\dir_main

:loopstart
set dirname=subdir%counter%
md %dirname%
echo %dirname%

dir /b | findstr /v /i "subdir*"> %temp%\temp.txt && for /l %%l in (1,1,%filesperfolder%) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r "^" %temp%\temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%%l:"') do @move %%b %dirname%\%%b >nul

set /a counter=%counter%+1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %temp%\temp.txt ^| find /c /v ""') do set _filesmoved=%%a
del %temp%\temp.txt
IF %_filesmoved% LSS 50 goto done

goto loopstart

:done
cls
echo All files were moved!!
pause
exit
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have and point out the problems with it.

Comment: Post updated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disliked the script you found as it was hard to read and used a temp file to keep track of the list of files.  (Also, it evidently doesn't work, so there's that.)

```batch
@echo off
SET /a cnt=50
SET /a fnum=0

FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /a-d *.csv') DO (
    CALL :moveFile "%%f"
)

GOTO :end

:moveFile
    IF "%cnt%" equ "50" CALL :makeDir

    move "%~1" "%fnum%\%~1"
    SET /a cnt+=1

    GOTO :EOF

:makeDir
    SET /a fnum+=1
    mkdir %fnum%
    SET /a cnt=0

    GOTO :EOF

:end
```

Comment: Since I'm new to batch script, can you explain to me what does /b /a-d stand for?

Comment: `/b` print only the names of the files without any extra information. `/a-d` not a directory.  When I originally wrote this I hadn't remembered that your scenario was specifically for csv files, so I wrote it for any files.

Comment: Also, for future reference, almost any command/command line utility program will display usage information if you run it with `/?`.  So like `dir /?` would get you the info about `/b /a`

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, btw you did add *csv for only csv files :D

Comment: @Gerhard Ah, right.  I've gotten to used to bash.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it. We test if there are still files in the directory, if there is, create a new directory and copy 50 files.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set fold_cnt=1
:test
set file_cnt=50
dir /a-d YL*.csv | findstr /IRC:"File(s)"
     if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
         mkdir !fold_cnt!
       ) else (
         goto :eof
   )
for %%i in (YL*.csv) do (
     if not !file_cnt! equ 0 (
         set /a file_cnt-=1
         move /Y "%%i" "!fold_cnt!\%%i"
      )
   )
set /a fold_cnt+=1
goto test
```

Comment: I hadn't known that batch supports `+=`.  Cool

Comment: @dx_over_dt That is the prefered method to calculated yes. `set /a var+=1` also looks a lot better than `set /a var=%var% + 1`

Comment: Agreed.  I was just going off some scripts I found online.  It's been a long time since I was competent with batch.

Comment: What does `!file_cnt!` do?  Like what are the exclamation points for?

Comment: @dx_over_dt When `set`ting a variable and using it inside a parenthesized code block, the variable needs to be expanded at execution time and not when parsed. So we do `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to achieve this. We however need to tell `cmd` which variable needs to be expanded, so we replace `%` with `!`. You can do `set /?` and `setlocal /?` from `cmd` to see the detailed explanation.

Comment: Ahh, gotchya.  Originally I tried to use enabledelayedexpansion, but I didn't know I had to use !'s

Comment: @dx_over_dt so a simple example. run from a batch file `for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (set var=%%i` and then next line `echo %var%` and close the parenthesis in the line after `)` You will see the variable will not update. but if you `enabledelayedexpansion` and then simply do `echo !var!` it gets expanded at runtime and it will count 1,2,3... etc.

Comment: One way around it is to use `call echo %%var%%` but that has its drawbacks as well.

Comment: For some reason, I tested on the same batch of files (made a backup :) ), and the code doesn't seem to work. ):

Comment: Does capital commands such as GOTO:EOF and SET makes a difference to its non-capital counterparts?

Comment: What do you mean by does seem to work? Can you clarify what happens? no, capitals on the functions does not make a difference.